# Auto-approve all comments in Comments Plugin

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments, facebook-social-plugins

Is there a way to auto-approve and make all the Comments Plugin's comments public by default?

Also I really need to know on what basis the comments are held for moderation. On some pages, they are public by default, on others they end up in moderation queue.

---------- Update 0 ---------

I removed **fb:admins**, the moderation UI has disappeared, but the moderation is still in effect. I get the admin UI when I load the page logged in with the App admin creds, and the I can see the comments are in the moderation queue (even new ones). I have even ticked "Make every post visible to everyone by default".

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: There is an open bug report for this issue. http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/117814361658299

Answer (score 12):

I have determined the cause of this issue.

It turns out that if you try and post to a comment box using a 'fresh' facebook account, these comments are automatically added to the moderation queue. This makes sense as the users posting these comments look like spammers.

Comment: Thanks! I was using my facebook 'test' account to test the auto-approved function, and it didn't work at all. Good to know it's because my 'fresh test' account :)

Comment: Thank you! This was very hard information to find. If you approve the comment by the 'fresh' user, will all their future comments be automatically approved? Or does each comment by that user have to be approved before Facebook determines the user is no longer 'fresh'?

Answer (score 0):

Go into any of your page with facebook comments included.

And then click the settings which is top right corner of comments box.

Find

> Make every post public by default

among options

and click that option and save.