# Facebook Comments Plugin Moderation Mode Setting not working

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-social-plugins

I have the Facebook Comments plugin set up on a website, and it's working, however the setting "Make every post visible to everyone by default" doesn't seem to be working. All posts remain invisible to everyone except the moderator and the poster.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using facebook test account to post comments, you will face this problem *_^ (i.e regardless the moderation settings that you have specified)

check this [Auto-approve all comments in Comments Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455247/auto-approve-all-comments-in-comments-plugin)