# Facebook comments, all comments end up in moderation

Tags: facebook, drupal, facebook-comments

Somehow all comments that I put on my website end up in moderation, despite that in settings I have set up " Make every post public by default." Is someone would like to help that's url for testing:  http://notiblog.pl/urz%C4%99dy-i-instytucje/urz%C4%85d-testowy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its basically because its a new facebook account. It is put in the moderation queue. I know its a hassle we could do without but comes with its perks as well.

The "new" means fresh. Seems someone had already answered it over here :

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455247/auto-approve-all-comments-in-comments-plugin)

Comment: So all comments, even those users that have got "not fresh" accounts will end up in moderation? or is it just comments from fresh accounts ending up in moderation?

Comment: Only with "fresh"/"new" accounts.

Comment: the accounts that I'm using are older than a year but not used for long time, and comments made from that accounts are moderated, any chabce that you could post comment on that page to check if that will be moderated?

Comment: I respectfully decline. It needs logging in with my fB account and then posting so ...

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for your help anyway